# How to create View and Download Links for files on Amazon S3

Tags: php, amazon-web-services

I am developing an App which uploads files i.e. images,pdfs,text documents to Amazon S3. I am able to upload the files using S3.php class.

I have to store two links to the file in the database , the first link is the link to view the file in the browser if it is an image or a pdf document. The second link is to download the file.

I am able to generate the URL for each of the file using :

```
$url = $s3->getAuthenticatedUrl($bucket,$uri,$expiry)
```

But clicking the URL starts downloading the file, also this URL has an expiry time. But I have to store the links in database for longer time. 
I also have to display the images and pdfs inside the browser, How can I generate the links. Kindly help...

Comment: Generate the signed links when you fetch them from the database, before rendering the page...

Comment: Well that's a solution I first thought about, but its not an efficient one, because AWS charges for every pull and put request, so client is more interested in as low as possible requests to AWS Server.